# query_posts() with multiple meta data comparisons

Tags: query-posts, search, meta-query

I have a bunch of posts belonging to category 6, each having the same meta fields. I'm interested in two fields in particular: "pce_monday_open" and "pce_monday_close", both of which have numeric values.

I want to run a query_posts() query that returns posts in category 6, and where some number, $pce_time, is in between the values of the two meta fields. My current query argument is:

```
$pce_arg = array(
'cat' => 6,
'meta_query' => array(
array('key' => 'pce_monday_open', 'value' => $pce_time, 'compare' => '<=' ),
array('key' => 'pce_monday_close', 'value' => $pce_time, 'compare' => '>=' )
)
);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working, and no posts are being returned. My search seems to work fine with other query parameters (such as searching other meta fields for an exact match), so I think there is an issue with my comparison parameters.

Is there something obviously wrong with what I've written? Or is it correct, and the issue might lie elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

First, **do not `query_posts`**; use [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead. That being said, I assume that `pce_monday_open` is lower than `pce_monday_close` and that you want posts between `pce_monday_open` and `pce_monday_close`, so I think your comparison logic is wrong. Also, you may need to set the relationship between the two meta query arrays:

```
$pce_arg = array(
    'cat' => 6,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'pce_monday_open',
            'value'   => $pce_time,
            'compare' => '<=' ),
        array('
            key'      => 'pce_monday_close',
            'value'   => $pce_time,
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $pce_arg );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        //Loop on each post
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply cybmeta. "pce_monday_open" is indeed lower than "pce_monday_close", however I don't understand why you'd switch the comparison operators. Take the following meta query:

`array('key' => $metakey, 'value' => $metavalue, 'compare'=> '>=')`

Will this not return posts where the `$metakey` field has a value greater than or equal to `$metavalue`? If so, then what I had made sense I think, because I wanted the value of `pce_monday_open` to be less than `$pce_time` and `pce_monday_close` to be greater.  

Thanks for your other comment about WP_query too!